# How to find the particular style in inspect--->element into Javascript File

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new learning react/javascript, I edit a particular style in the inspect element, I was trying to find the corresponding style in the Javascript file, I have tried lots of ways, but not able to find it, is there any way to located the style that I edit in the inspect element?

Comment: you could search for that `classname` in the editor. I don't think you could link that file from devtools to your code editor though.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the file source of various styles in the Chrome DevTools Styles pane. The pane shows increasingly broad CSS style definitions for a selected element and the file location of those definitions. If you implement HTML inline styles, then the overridden styles are still shown with a strikethrough.

[image: Screenshot from Chrome DevTools]